# onAttachFragment not called by Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity in which a FrameLayout is used as a fragment container. I would like to set this FrameLayout clickable whenever a fragment is added in this FrameLayout (To avoid every click event to pass through the fragment).

I've read that I can use `onAttachFragment` to detect when a fragment is added to the Activity.

So I have added this code in my activity :

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragment.getView().setClickable(true);
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}
```

But for some reason this method is never called.

Comment: It is good practice to have the call to default implementation first, so try to rearrange super call as the first call in the handler. Apart from that, this seems like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you mean by `avoid every click event to pass through the fragment` ?

Comment: Try this  @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        Log.d("onAttachFragment","onAttachFragment android.app.Fragment ");
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Fragment`'s view wont have been inflated when `onAttachFragment()` is called. To quote from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment)):

> `void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)`
>
> Called when a Fragment is being
>   attached to this activity, immediately **after** the call to its
>   `Fragment.onAttach()` method and **before** `Fragment.onCreate()`.

As such, calling `fragment.getView()` doesn't make sense, as the view isn't inflated until `onCreateView()` (which occurs just after `onCreate()`).

As an altnerative method, you could either just set the `Fragment`'s layout as clickable or not as part of its arguments:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment getInstance(boolean isClickable) {

        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putBoolean("key", isClickable);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;

    }

    //...
    private boolean isClickable() {
        return getArguments().getBoolean("key");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = //Inflate view...

        view.setClickable(isClickable());
        return view;

    }
```

Or, you can approach this another way and use an `interface` which is called inside `onCreateView()` of your `Fragment`, where you "ask" the `Activity` it is attached to whether its root view should be clickable or not.